# Сравнение строк в bash

Tags: bash

Есть код

```
#!/bin/bash

SRCD='/media/sysadmin2/Data/autodialer/' #исходная директория
RCVD='/media/sysadmin2/Data/autodialer/backup/' #принимающая директория
LOCK='/media/sysadmin2/Data/autodialer/backup/zvonar.lock'

if [ -z "$(ls -A ${SRCD})" ]; then # если пусто, то выходим
        exit 0
else # инчае проверяем lock файл
        if [[ -f $LOCK ]]; then # если есть lock файл, оповещаем и выходим
                echo "Копирование невозможно! Файл уже занят другой программой"
                exit 0
        else # если нет то копируем файл и запускаем работу
                # rsync -aAv --delete-after --ignore-errors ${SRCD}*.txt ${RCVD}                
                # rm -f ${SRCD}*.txt
                # chmod 644 ${RCVD}*.txt
                # chown asterisk:asterisk ${RCVD}*.txt
                # nohup ${RCVD}zvonar.sh > ${RCVD}zvonar.log &
                filename=$(basename ${RCVD}*.txt)
                result="${filename%.*}"
                echo $result
                
                if [ $result == 'diallist' ]; then
                    echo "diallist верен"
                elif [ $result == 'tel' ]; then
                    echo "tel верен"
                else
                     echo "FAIL"
                fi
        fi
fi
```

В директории RCVD есть 2 файла diallist.txt и tel.txt
Я пытаюсь сравнить строки и вывести результать в echo
Но скрипт проверяет только один файл а не все какие там есть.
Как сделать чтобы скрипт вывел результат для обоих файлов?

Пробовал добавить цикл, но тогда для второго файла выводит FAIL

```
for file in ${RCVD}*.txt; do
        filename=$(basename $file)
        result="${filename%.*}"
        if [ $result == 'diallist' ]; then
                echo "diallist верен"
                # nohup ${RCVD}zvonar.sh > ${RCVD}zvonar.log &
        elif [ $result == 'tel' ]; then
                echo "tel верен"
                # nohup ${RCVD}zvonar.sh > ${RCVD}zvonar.log &
        else
                echo "FAIL"
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решил с помощью цикла for. Оказалось имя файла было другим:)

Решил свою проблему таким образом

```
#!/bin/bash

SRCD='/media/autodialer/' #исходная директория
RCVD='/etc/asterisk/script/zvonar/' #принимающая директория
LOCK='/media/autodialer/zvonar.lock' #файл блокировки

if [ -z "$(ls -A ${SRCD})" ]; then # если пусто, то выходим
        exit 0
else # инчае проверяем lock файл
        if [[ -f $LOCK ]]; then # если есть lock файл, оповещаем и выходим
                echo "Копирование невозможно! Файл уже занят другой программой"
                exit 0
        else # если нет то копируем файлы и запускаем работу zvonar, предварительно назначив разрешения всем txt файлам
                rsync -aAv --delete-after --ignore-errors ${SRCD}*.txt ${RCVD}                
                rm -f ${SRCD}*.txt
                chmod 644 ${RCVD}*.txt
                chown asterisk:asterisk ${RCVD}*.txt
                
                for file in ${RCVD}*.txt; do # пробегаемся по всем файлам в директории и сравниваем по условию. Исходя из условия выполняем тот скрипт который нужно в фоновом режиме
                        
                        filename=$(basename $file)
                        result="${filename%.*}"

                        if [ $result == 'IT_diallist' ]; then
                                nohup ${RCVD}zvonar_it.sh > ${RCVD}zvonar.log &
                        elif [ $result == 'DR_diallist' ]; then
                                nohup ${RCVD}zvonar_dr.sh > ${RCVD}zvonar.log &
                        else
                                exit 0
                        fi
                done
        fi
fi
```

**IT_diallist** и **DR_diallist** это имена файлов которые используются у меня.
Циклом **for** я перебрал все файлы с расширением ***.txt** и сравнил с тем что у меня написано в условии программы

Comment: Пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы.
[Постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию.
Изложите свои предложения.
Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).
Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].